# ASP.NET redirect the page to a new URL

Tags: asp.net, html, redirect

I have a site which has a start up page called Test.htm. The site is temporarily down and we want to display an error page when the site loads. I have a page called error.htm. How is this possible ??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET provides three main methods that allow you to trap and respond to errors when they occur: **Page_Error**, **Application_Error**, and the **application configuration** file (Web.config).

1.The Page_Error event handler provides a way to trap errors that occur at the **page level**
2.You can use the Application_Error event handler to trap errors that occur in your **application**
3.If you do not call Server.ClearError or trap the error in the Page_Error or Application_Error event handler, the error is handled based on the settings in the  section of the Web.config file. 
In the  section, you can specify a **redirect page** as a default error page (defaultRedirect) or specify to a particular page based on the HTTP error code that is raised.

e.g. You need to add following code in Global.asax page **customErrors** section to redirect the user to a custom page

`<customErrors defaultRedirect="http://hostName/applicationName/errorStatus.htm" mode="On">
                </customErrors>`

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but have looked a response.redirect?

[In ASP.NET MVC, how does response.redirect work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822562/in-asp-net-mvc-how-does-response-redirect-work)

Answer (score 0):

Take it ["offline"](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19653/Taking-an-ASPNET-20-Application-Offline.htm)

See: [IIS: Redirect ALL requests to one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300416/iis-redirect-all-requests-to-one-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can hack your web.config to force your application into returning 404's when requested.  Then override the 404 error page to be you "error" page.

```
<httpRuntime enable="false" />

<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/errors/GeneralError.aspx">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **app_offline.htm** page. If the asp.net find this page on root, then what ever you ask its show this page, and the site is down.

Second way, that is not bring the site down, on Application Begin Request, make the redirect to the page you like as:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

    // just double check in case that htm proceed from asp.net
    if(!cTheFile.EndsWith("test.htm"))
    {
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("test.htm", true);
         return;
    }
}
```