# Redirect to default.aspx in the solution root folder instead of RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I redirect the following action (MVC) to an aspx page outside the Views folder? Whatever I do it redirects to an action inside the Account folder. In other words instead of

```
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

I want to redirect to default.aspx in the solution root folder (mydomain.com/default.aspx). Response.redirect doesn't work in this context. Here is the code:

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Response.Redirect("/default.aspx");
```

Comment: Response.Redirect("../default.aspx");

Comment: Response.Redirect will prevent the action to be completed. The user will be redirected before he/she is authenticated....

Comment: As noted in this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822562/in-asp-net-mvc-how-does-response-redirect-work) your code execution continue after `Response.Redirect` in `mvc` and also as I debugged on my code