# C# MVC Controller redirect to Tel, SMS, and mailto links

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I have a MVC website in which I would like to have a website URL hit and then depending on the parameters passed in, display the native phone interface, email interface, or SMS interface.

I can get each of the interfaces on a smartphone by typing in the interface in a web browser. For example if I go into safarai on iphone and type tel:55555555 the phone prompt will appear with 55555555 filled in.

How could I redirect to the interfaces from an MVC controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a controller action to your controller that calls Response.Redirect with the appropriate protocol. For example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Phone()
    {
        Response.Redirect("tel:5551212");
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

When this controller action is hit, it prompts the browser to redirect and attempt to open the phone app. In my case, it opens Skype. You can modify your controller action, of course, to redirect using different protocols based upon parameters.

The URL to call this controller action is simply http://whatever/home/phone. You can also shorten this controller action to:

```
public ActionResult Phone()
{
    return Redirect("tel:5551212");
}
```

That is a little prettier, in my opinion. There is a similar question answered here:

[In ASP.NET MVC, how does response.redirect work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822562/in-asp-net-mvc-how-does-response-redirect-work)